# Merging/Append a DataFrame with itself results in new columns

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge, append

I have the following merge operation:

```
data_static = pandas.merge(data_static, data_output[['TICKER', 'DATE', 'rolling_vola_40', 'rolling_vola_80', 'f_rolling_vola_40', 'f_rolling_vola_80', 'rolling_vola_prev_annum', 'rolling_vola_post_annum']], how='left', on=['TICKER', 'DATE'])
```

My problem now is that this results into the following headers:

```
;YEAR;DATE;TICKER;LONG_COMP_NAME;ISSUER_INDUSTRY;INDUSTRY_SECTOR;COUNTRY;ACCOUNTING_STANDARD;ACCOUNTING_STANDARD_OVERRIDE;EQY_FUND_CRNCY;INDEX;DATE_PREV;DATE_NEXT;rolling_vola_40_x;rolling_vola_80_x;f_rolling_vola_40_x;f_rolling_vola_80_x;rolling_vola_prev_annum_x;rolling_vola_post_annum_x;rolling_vola_40_y;rolling_vola_80_y;f_rolling_vola_40_y;f_rolling_vola_80_y;rolling_vola_prev_annum_y;rolling_vola_post_annum_y
```

I want the data to go into the same column, like this:

```
;YEAR;DATE;TICKER;LONG_COMP_NAME;ISSUER_INDUSTRY;INDUSTRY_SECTOR;COUNTRY;ACCOUNTING_STANDARD;ACCOUNTING_STANDARD_OVERRIDE;EQY_FUND_CRNCY;INDEX;DATE_PREV;DATE_NEXT;rolling_vola_40;rolling_vola_80;f_rolling_vola_40;f_rolling_vola_80;rolling_vola_prev_annum;rolling_vola_post_annum;
```

So instead of going next to each other like this (example):

```
    TICKER   Val1_x   Val2_x   Val3_x   Val1_y   Val2_y   Val3_y
    A        80       6        1        NaN      NaN      NaN
    B        NaN      NaN      NaN      10       12       14
```

I want them to be like this:

```
    TICKER   Val1     Val2     Val3
    A        80       6        1
    B        10       12       14
```

My merge joins on the columns `TICKER` and `DATE`, so don't be confused by the sample data.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. The issue is real and I have not seen a solution that works yet. I've read every single stackoverflow post on the right and did so for the next level.

Answer (score 1):

The work around here is to use `append` first and then `merge` them at the end:

```
data_store = pandas.DataFrame(columns=('TICKER', 'DATE', 'rolling_vola_40', 'rolling_vola_80', 'f_rolling_vola_40', 'f_rolling_vola_80', 'rolling_vola_prev_annum', 'rolling_vola_post_annum'))

for index, row in data_static.iterrows():
    data_output = vol(row['TICKER'], row['DATE'], row['DATE_PREV'], row['DATE_NEXT'])
    if type(data_output) != type(None):
        data_store = data_store.append(data_output[['TICKER', 'DATE', 'rolling_vola_40', 'rolling_vola_80', 'f_rolling_vola_40', 'f_rolling_vola_80', 'rolling_vola_prev_annum', 'rolling_vola_post_annum']])

data_static = pandas.merge(data_static, data_store[['TICKER', 'DATE', 'rolling_vola_40', 'rolling_vola_80', 'f_rolling_vola_40', 'f_rolling_vola_80', 'rolling_vola_prev_annum', 'rolling_vola_post_annum']], how='left', on=['TICKER', 'DATE'])
data_static.to_csv('test.csv', sep=';', encoding='utf-8')
```